# Remove duplicates in a collection

Tags: c#, linq, list

How do I remove dupliactes in a collection? For example:

```
List<double> somelist=new List<double>{2, 2, 3};
```

What LINQ method should I use?

And try to make it simple please.

Comment: Just use a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) and you won't have any duplicates to begin with.

Comment: Are you trying to get a new collection without the duplicates, or are you do you want the same collection just without the dups?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Enumerable.Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) is probably what you're looking for.

```
var somelist = new List<double>{2, 2, 3}.Distinct();

// somelist now contains 2, 3
```

Comment: And it simply gets rid of duplicates?

Comment: @EdwardKarak You should refer to the documentation for [`Enumerable.Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx)

Comment: As long as your `T` from `IEnumerable<T>` implements `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods property `Enumerable.Distinct` will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a `HashSet<double>` instead of `List<double>`.

Comment: Why? Also that dosen't really answer the question